# Inconsistent focus by TextInput in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a `TextInput` that looks like this.

```
 <TextInput
  autoFocus
  style={styles.inputText}
  placeholder="Type username here here"
  ref={input => { this.textUser = input }}
  value={this.state.user}
  onChangeText={(user) => this.setState({user})}
  />
```

Now, this is inside a component that is called by a `TabNavigator` which happens also to be buried inside a `StackNavigator`. You can see the raw visual representation below:

```
[Label of Tabs below]
Home Tab (has list of users to choose from)
     | 
     ---Show Summary of User
        |
        ---Show more detail about the User

AddUser Tab
```

Every time I click the Tab named `AddUser` that has the above `TextInput` I could see the cursor blinking on my `TextInput` and obviously the focus is working. However, if I press on one of the list (it has a list of users with summary of information) on my `Home` Tab and it shows a component, once I go back and press the Tab `AddUser` again, the focus is gone and there is no blinking cursor. Additionally, if I click also the List of users that I mentioned earlier that shows summary information of the user and then I click further down that shows the more Detail information about the user (See illustration above). Then go back (twice) to Home then click again the `Add User` it works without problem meaning focus is there and the cursor is blinking.

Below is a snippet code inside the Summary View of Users component:

```
 <View style={{flex:10, flexDirection:'column', justifyContent:'center'}}>
      <View style={{flex:8, marginTop:40, marginBottom:40, alignItems:'center', justifyContent:'center', backgroundColor:lightBlue}}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:36, color:black, fontWeight:'bold'}}>{user.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:24, color:gray, fontStyle:'italic'}}>{user.totalAchievements} </Text>
       </View>
       <View style={{flex:1, justifyContent:'flex-start'}}>
             <Button
                raised
                backgroundColor={white}
                color={black}
                icon={{name: 'add-circle-outline', color:black}}
                onPress={()=>this.gotoAddDetail(user)}
                title='Add Detail' />

       </View>
 </View>
```

I've been debugging this for almost a whole day and can't figure out what could be the problem. I am new to `React` and `React Native` by the way.

Comment: I find `autoFocus` buggy and hard to test, try using `element.focus()` and `Keyboard.dismiss()` for better control

Comment: David the `Keyboard.dismiss()` did it! Thank you very much. I tried already removing the `autoFocus` before with `element.focus()` but also to no avail. What do you think does the `Keyboard.dismiss()` do that removes this inconsistency? Post your answer by the way so that I could accept it. Thanks again and GOD bless.

Comment: Wow, the `Keyboard.dismiss()` works for awhile then it has the same problem again. :-(